# Remove the Json element by key from an unknown JSON Formate in JAVA

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I need to remove the complete JSON object by its key name, **I have random JSON every time, I need to find a particular element and remove it.**
for example, I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "abc":{
        "remove_me": "123456"
    }
}
```

but may next time I may have the following

```
{
    "abc": {
        "xyz": {
            "test": "test"
        }
    },
     "abc1": {
        "xyz1": {
            "remove_me": "232233",
            "test": "dfefd",

        }
    }
}
```

every time I have a different JSON format, even in more complex formats. but the key I have to remove the element is `remove_me`

I am doing it in Java, please help!

Comment: Are you using a JSON-parsing library?

Comment: Which JSON library do you use?

Comment: as an option, you could implement logic by yourself: convert json into `Map<String, Object>`, then traverse map similar to deep first search logic (checking whether map's value is list, map or any other object, and invoking method recursively), and if key during traversing is `remove_me`, you need to remove it.

Comment: I am using com.fasterxml.jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. This will iterate and remove each matched key.

```
private static void iterateJSONAndRemoveKey(JSONObject jObj) {
    Set<String> keys = jObj.keySet();
    for(String key : keys) {
        if(key.equals("remove_me")) {
            jObj.remove(key);
        }
        else if(jObj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
            JSONObject subObject = (JSONObject) jObj.get(key);
            iterateJSONAndRemoveKey(subObject);
        }
        else if(jObj.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray) jObj.get(key); 
            for(int i = 0; i < jArray.size(); i++) {
                if(jArray.get(i) instanceof JSONObject) {
                iterateJSONAndRemoveKey((JSONObject)jArray.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to check that elements in arrays are objects too.  Otherwise if the JSON contains, for example, `[1, 2, 3]`, you'll get an error.  You might also want to handle arrays containing other arrays.

Comment: how can I use this by using I am using com.fasterxml.jackson library? I apologize, I did not mention the library earlier.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked for me by making two small changes.** 1) add return statement after jObj.remove(key), 2) used length() instead of jArray.size() in for loop. **  Many Thanks! below is the complete code.

Answer (score 1):

As I was using **com.fasterxml.jackson** Library, Below is the solution.

```
private static void iterateJSONAndRemoveKey(JsonNode rootNode,String toRemove) throws Exception {
        Iterator<String> keysIterator = rootNode.fieldNames();
        while (keysIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = keysIterator.next();
            if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(toRemove)){
                ((ObjectNode) rootNode).remove(toRemove);
                return;
            }else if (rootNode.isObject()){
                   iterateJSONAndRemoveKey(rootNode.get(key),toRemove);
            }else if (rootNode.isArray()){
                ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) rootNode;
                for (JsonNode node : arrayNode) {
                    iterateJSONAndRemoveKey(node,toRemove);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Asked answer helped me to write the logic in Jackson library.